# How to fix a problem with IURLHelper (add singleton on startup.cs doesn't work) ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I was trying to create a pagination of my website. I'm learning from book "ASP.NET Core 2" Adam Freeman. These lines: 
`IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);`
`TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");`

return null. What is the problem?

This is a asp.net core 2.2 application.

Code that doesn't work:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
     IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
     TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
     for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
     {
          TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
          tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction, new { ProductPage = i });
          tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
     }
     output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
}
```

I added this to a startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(factory =>
{
     var actionContext = factory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
     return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
});
```

I added a unit tests and It's should return a `<a href="test/pageX"></a>` for all the pages, but it's return nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistakenly added the `anchor` to itself, rather trying adding it to the container `div`

```
TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
{
     TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
     tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction, new { ProductPage = i });     
     // tag was being added to itself, rather add it the container `div`
     // tag.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
     result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good solution, but i have another problem. It's make a href, but there isn't any content. Can you help me with that? This is a line in cshtml: <div page-model="@Model.PagingInfo" page-action="List"></div>. Are you need something else?

Comment: All i had to do was just write tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString()); before result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);. Thank you Majid for help and for your time.